# Most of the records in dataset get assigned to one cluster - kmeans clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science, k-means

I converted text data to tokens using tfidf vectorizer and performed kmeans clustering on it that grouped similar text data into a particular cluster. I generated 14 clusters. Most of the clusters contain homogeneous text data. However, one particular cluster contains one third of records and does not have homogeneous records.

I tried using LSA and running kmeans clustering on lsa output but I get similar output.

```
tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,analyzer='word',stop_words='english',lowercase=True)

train_tfidf_vectorizer=tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train.TERM_ReasonToSearch_String)

clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=14, random_state=42,init='k-means++').fit_predict(train_tfidf_vectorizer)
train['cluster14_Kmeans'] = clusters

train.groupby('cluster14_Kmeans')['cluster14_Kmeans'].count()
```

Output:

[image: Clustering Output]

Cluster 9 has 46/130 records that are non homogeneous

How can I improve the clustering results?

Comment: That is the typical behavior on short texts, and why KMeans is pretty useless on such data in practice. But it probably isn't even KMeans fault, but the problem itself is ill-defined.

Comment: Yes, the cluster has short texts, so what should be the ideal way to cluster when the dataset has both short and long texts.

Comment: I do *not* think there is any that works reliably. I think it is not possible with so little data to do this right. But maybe word vectors help, if they are trained on the right kind of big data.